# Envoy (Service mesh) and the term Clusters

Tags: service, cluster-computing, mesh, envoyproxy

We need to learn envoy well enough to create a service mesh.  In the Envoy Documentation they talk about "Clusters" without defining the term.  Are they talking about Kubernetis Clusters, or does this term have a specific meaning when configuring Envoy?  (for a cluster of servers)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the definition in the [terminology documentation](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.21.1/intro/arch_overview/intro/terminology):

> **Cluster**: A cluster is a group of logically similar upstream hosts that Envoy connects to. Envoy discovers the members of a cluster via service discovery. It optionally determines the health of cluster members via active health checking. The cluster member that Envoy routes a request to is determined by the load balancing policy.

Only the first sentence (*A cluster is a group of logically similar upstream hosts that Envoy connects to.*) is needed to understand what a cluster is. It has nothing to do with Kubernetes, *cluster* is an Envoy term.

Let's say that you have two hosts running the same service, and you want that Envoy connects to one of these hosts (load-balancing the traffic), then you will define a *cluster* with these two hosts:

```yaml
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 8080
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: AUTO
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: backend
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: service

  clusters:
  - name: service
    connect_timeout: 15s
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: service
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 10.0.0.43
                port_value: 80
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 10.0.0.44
                port_value: 80
```

In this example, a request made by a client to Envoy on port `8080` will be forwarded to one of the *cluster* hosts (`10.0.0.43:80` or `10.0.0.44:80`).

You can find more documentation about clusters here: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.21.1/intro/arch_overview/upstream/upstream.